# why after I created a new table using go-pg, and found that the name of the new table changed?

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, go-pg

why after I created a  new table using go-pg, and found that the name of the new table changed?
for example,the struct name is "story" and it became "stories" in pg.

[image: 1]

```
type Newtb struct {
  Id     int64
  Name   string
  Emails []string
}



func createTest(db *pg.DB) error {
  err := db.Model((*Newtb)(nil)).CreateTable(&orm.CreateTableOptions{
    IfNotExists: true,
  })
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return err
  }
  return nil
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvbuc.png)

My struct name is "Newtb" and it turned "newtbs" in postgreSQL.
Can someone explain to me why an 's' was added to the table name?

Comment: Can you please share your code so we can review?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question.

Comment: Because you didn't read the docs [Models](https://pg.uptrace.dev/models/). See `Table name`.

Answer (score 0):

> Table name and alias are automatically derived from the struct name by
> underscoring it. Table name is also pluralized, for example struct
> Genre gets table name genres and alias genre. You can override the
> default table name and alias using tableName field:

```
    type Genre struct {
    tableName struct{} `pg:"genres,alias:g"`
}
```